# Google API Multiple Path Color

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get different colors that are stored in an array to different path drawn on Google map. From my code, I can get only one color for all the path. but I want different colors for each path.[Here is the result I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjiAO.png)

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var myarray=<?php echo json_encode($videosetting); ?>;
document.write("<br>array <br>")
document.write(myarray)
document.write("<br>array[0] <br>")
document.write(myarray[0])

document.write("<br>array[1] <br>")
document.write(myarray[1])

var count= <?php echo $count; ?>;
document.write(count)

var markes=[];

for (var i=0; i<count ;i++) {
    markes[i]= [
        {
            "title": 'Reduit',
            "lat": myarray[i][2],
            "lng": myarray[i][3],
            "description": 'reduit'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Bagatelle',
            "lat": myarray[i][4],
            "lng": myarray[i][5],
            "description": 'bagatelle'
        }
    ,
            {
            "title": 'Bagatelle',
            "lat": myarray[i][8],
            "lng": myarray[i][9],
            "description": 'bagatelle'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Reduit',
            "lat": myarray[i][6],
            "lng": myarray[i][7],
            "description": 'reduit'
        }



];
}


window.onload = function () {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markes[0][1].lat, markes[0][1].lng),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();



//Creating Markers


    var data=[];
    var myLatlng=[];
    var marker=[];
    //var lat_lng = new Array();
    var lat_lng = [];
    for (var i=0;i<count; i++) {
           for (j = 0; j < markes[i].length; j++) {
        data[j] = markes[i][j];
        myLatlng[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(data[j].lat, data[j].lng);
        lat_lng.push(myLatlng[j]);
        //lat_lng[j]=myLatlng[j];
        marker[j] = new google.maps.Marker
            (
                {
                 position: myLatlng[j],
                    map: map,
                title: data[j].title

                }
            );


        latlngbounds.extend(marker[j].position);

        (
            function (marker, data) 
            {
              google.maps.event.addListener
              ( marker, "click", function (e) 
                        {
                                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    );
            }
            )(marker[j], data[j]);
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }



    //Initialize the Path Array


    //Initialize the Direction Service


    //Set the Path Stroke Color

   var color=['#0EF022','#FF0000','#FFFF00','#00FF00','#00FFFF','#0000FF','#000000','FFFFFF'];
   var src_des=[];
   var j=0;
   for (i=0;i<lat_lng.length;i++) {
    src_des[j]=[lat_lng[i],lat_lng[i+1]];

    j+=1;
    i+=1;
   }





 for (var t = 0;t < src_des.length; t++) 
 {
 //Intialize the Direction Service
 var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 if ((t + 1) < lat_lng.length) 
 {
  var src = src_des[t][0];
  var des = src_des[t][1];
  service.route(
  {
    origin: src,
    destination: des,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, 
  function(result, status) 
  {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
    {
      // new path for the next result
      var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
      //Set the Path Stroke Color
      // new polyline for the next result
      var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(
      {
        map: map,
        strokeColor: color[t]
      });
      poly.setPath(path);
      for (var k = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; k < len; k++) 
      {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[k]);
        bounds.extend(result.routes[0].overview_path[k]);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
    } else alert("Directions Service failed:" + status);
  });
  }
 }






 }// window.onload = function () 
 </script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 100%; height: 800px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with iterating through loops that call asynchronous services.  One solution (as shown in the answer to [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)) is to use function closure to associate the loop variable with the callback function instance:

```
for (var t = 0; t < src_des.length; t++) {
  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  if ((t + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
    var src = src_des[t][0];
    var des = src_des[t][1];
    service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      },
      // function closure on "color"
      (function(color) {
        return function(result, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            // new path for the next result
            var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
            //Set the Path Stroke Color
            // new polyline for the next result
            var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
              map: map,
              strokeColor: color
            });
            poly.setPath(path);
            for (var k = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; k < len; k++) {
              path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[k]);
              bounds.extend(result.routes[0].overview_path[k]);
              map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
          } else alert("Directions Service failed:" + status);
        }
      // the value for this callback function
      }(color[t])))
  };  
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/11yc829s/2/)

- for more information on function closures see [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Thanks a lot geocodezip and Reinhard. It is now working fine. Regards

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that was most useful in addressing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also if I like the code and explanations from geocodezip, here an alternative, which gives you with always changing colors a high flexibility especially in the case you don't know how many paths you write finally. Replace your color-array with following code:

```
var colorIndex_ = 0;
var COLORS = [["red", "#ff0000"], ["green","#008000"], ["blue", "#000080"], ["purple", "#800080"],
        ["light-purple", "#FF00FF"], ["brown", "#0xB70000"], ["light-green", "#00F000"], ["cyan", "#00FFFF"]];

function getColor(named) {
    return COLORS[(colorIndex_++) % COLORS.length][named ? 0 : 1];
}
```

In your polyline definition **replace:** strokeColor: color[t] **with:** strokeColor: getColor(false)

That's it. I've tested the code based on the example from geocodezip - works fine. So if you need a working example, let me know. br., Reinhard